# a JList scoll pane program that reads from a file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jscrollpane

I have the folowing code so far which outputs the make and price of a car,but i cant seem to figure out were to add the discritpion of the car so that it can also be diplayed.HELP!

I tried adding `discription[k] = st.nextToken();`, but the program did not run.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Lab22V3 extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {

    String[] products = new String[100];
    double[] prices = new double[100];
//string[]discription=new String[100]
    JLabel unitPrice;
    JList productList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lab22V3 x = new Lab22V3();
        x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        x.setTitle("Lab#22 Version#3");
        x.setSize(350, 250);
        x.setVisible(true);
    } // main

    public Lab22V3() // constructor
    {
        String s;
        StringTokenizer st;
        int k = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Lab22data.txt"));
            while ((s = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
                st = new StringTokenizer(s);
                products[k] = st.nextToken();
                //  discription[k] = st.nextToken();
                prices[k] = Double.valueOf(st.nextToken());
                ++k;
            } // while not EOF
            inFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        unitPrice = new JLabel();
        getContentPane().add(unitPrice, BorderLayout.NORTH)

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        productList = new JList(products);  // create a JList object
        productList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(productList);  // adding scrolling capability
        p.add(sp);
        getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        // Event registration
        productList.addListSelectionListener(this);
    } // constructor

    // Event handling
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        unitPrice.setText(" " + prices[productList.getSelectedIndex()]);
        //proddiscrition.setText(""+ discription[productList.getselectedIndex()];
    } // valueChanged
} // Lab22V3>
```

Here is the text file

```
1000    100.00  
A dozen of jokes
2000    5.91    
Used BMW
3000    19.28   
Cookie Jar
4000    21.90   
Birthday Cake
5000    35.28   
Used keyboard
6000    50.00   
Love
7000    92.27   
Gone with Wind
```

Comment: your code gives NumberFormatException.. At  prices[k] = Double.valueOf(st.nextToken());. I think first fix your code. Also i will display only product list.. You need to get it correct first..

Comment: +1, because I can't see reason for down-voting, SSCCE and full describtions about problem

Comment: at begin you needed `getContentPane().add(unitPrice, BorderLayout.NORTH);//0`, but I think that this is job for Vector & JTable, not for JList

Comment: I corrected the getContentPane.alsoIf i got it correct in the first place i wouldnt be asking for help :( .when i run it on eclipse its giving me the Gui frame with  the selection list and the price but no discription.I just cant get wat am missing!

Comment: *"but the program did not run."*  A program must walk, before it can run.  But on 2 more serious notes 1) What does it not do that you expected it to do?  What is your wquestion 2) The 'correct' part of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) does not mean 'working'.  Go back and read it again - *carefully* this time.

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/392176

Answer (score 0):

Angel918 has not been around for 5 months, so I am promoting his comment to answer per [Meta Suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a).

I got it. this is wat i kept messing up.thanks.

`unitPrice.setText(" " + prices[productList.getSelectedIndex()] +" "+productnames[productList.getSelectedIndex()]);`